# ActiveRecord .find() method fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to show each Category by name. I have a Post and Category model and each post only has one category.

This works: `<% @category = Category.find(3) %>`

This fails: `<% @category = Category.find(post.cat_id) %>`

My error: `Couldn't find Category with id= ".`

My view block:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= post.title %>
  <% @category = Category.find(post.cat_id) %>
  <%= @category.category %></td>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not ever do a query like `<% @category = Category.find(post.cat_id) %>` in your view. If you don't have the relationships configured in such a way that you can just call `post.category`, you should add a method to the Post model, something like:

```
def get_category
  Category.find(self.category_id).category
end
```

Then you can call `post.get_category` from your view and it will handle the query for you.

Comment: It give "error NoMethodError in Posts#index" when I add the method on the post controller. I also complete the relationship b/w the post and category model (in the post belongs_to :category and for category has_many :posts ).

Comment: Do you mean that you added it to the Post model? If you added it to the controller, it won't won't work. But you shouldn't have to do any of that if your relationship is setup right, you should be able to do `post.category.category`. I'd suggest changing the category's name to just `name`, calling `@category.category` is the kind of thing that'll cause problems for you down the road.